# Anchor position does not take top bar into account

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, hyperlinks, site-redesign

Since a few days, it occurs to me that when I click a time tag to jump straight to a(n) (new) answer, that the position of the anchor is wrong. As in, the anchor does put the answer on top of my screen, but it fails to take into account that there is a top bar 50 pixels high that obscures the first couple of lines.

[image: example of top bar obscuring answer text]

I'm using FF Quantum 61.0.1 (64-bit) on a W8 machine, with AdBlock Plus active.

Comment: on MSE too: [Top of answer covered by sticky top bar after clicking direct link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312508/307988)

Comment: As per [this answer on Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312705/267102), this issue now seems to be resolved.